# How to integrate opencv manager in an android app

Tags: android, opencv

I'm developing an android app that uses opencv libraries which is opencv manager app.
It requires opencv manager to be installed previously,
I want to integrate the opencv manager inside my application so that it does not require to install the opencv manager externally

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate OpenCV Manager in Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259309/how-to-integrate-opencv-manager-in-android-app)

Answer (score 4):

1 - Add the OpenCV library project to your workspace ( Use menu File -> Import -> Existing project in your workspace.)

2 - In application project add a reference to the OpenCV Java SDK in Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add select OpenCV Library - 2.4.8.

3 - Add a folder and name it "jni"

4 - Add an Android.mk file into jni folder. Its body should look like below:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# OpenCV
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

5 - Add an Application.mk file into jni folder. Its body should look like below:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

6 - Add this to your Activity

```
static {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            // Handle initialization error
        }
    }
```

7 - In case you have added following code to your Activity, comment out OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_8, this, mLoaderCallback);
You don't need to load OpenCV on resume event any more.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_8, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                //OpenCV loaded successfully
                break;
            default:
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Have a look at this  too:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization

Comment: Thanks,I haven't had a chance to try what you suggest.But I'm going to up-vote you for your solution as your solution seems reasonable.

Comment: OpenCVLoader.initDebug() still return false for me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Got another solution by installing open Cv from my app by using this lib
[AutoInstaller](https://github.com/a-voyager/AutoInstaller)