# OpenCV does not work on Nexus 9

Tags: android, opencv, arm, cross-platform

I am trying to use OpenCV library on a nexus 9 tablet(OS is lollipop, processor ARM64 - Tegra K1) but it does not work. If I install the OpenCV library and, then, run one of the OpenCV samples, it will appear:

"opencv library package was not found! Try to install it?"

When I tap yes, nothing happens. It probably does not work because Nexus 9 has an ARM64.

Is there a way of compile the OpenCV library and make it works on an ARM64 architecture?

Comment: It is possible to use openCV on a nexus9 (I have one) if the app bundles the library into it instead of using the Manager. But, we will likely have to wait for a complete version specifically for the new architecture.

Comment: Can I include all the OpenCV library in my app and then do not use the OpenCV Manager when my app runs?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, and I have set up a project that does that. There are certain things you need to remove, but it's totally workable.

Comment: How could I do that. Is there any tutorial that you know?

Comment: I learned by doing, from the Onyx sample project. https://github.com/onyx-intl/OnyxAndroidSample I just copied everything they did in eclipse.

Comment: Does it work for you on nexus 9?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421776/how-to-integrate-opencv-manager-in-an-android-app

Comment: That appears to be pretty close to what I do, yes.